# Somewhat Randomly create 3D points given 2 images

Tags: python, numpy

Somewhat Randomly create 3D points given 2 images

The goal is to create a set of n 3D coordinates (seeds) from 2 images. n could be any where from 100 - 1000 points.

I have 2 pure black and white images whose heights are the same and the widths variable. The size of the images can be as big as 1000x1000 pixels. I read them into numpy arrays and flattened the rgb codes to 1's (black) and zeros (white).

Here is example from processing 2 very small images:

```
In [6]: img1
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)

In [8]: img2
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Next, I create an index array to map all locations of black pixels for each image like so:

```
In [10]: np.transpose(np.nonzero(img1))
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 6],
       ...
```

I then want to extend each 2D black pixel for each image into 3D space. Where those 3D points intersect, I want to randomly grab n number of 3D ponts (seeds). Furthermore, as an enhancement, it would be even better if I could disperse these 3d points somewhat evenly in the 3d space to avoid 'clustering' of points where there are areas of greater black pixel density. But I haven't been able to wrap my head around that process yet.

Here's a visualization of the set up:

[image: line up images]
[image: extrude image]
[image: intersecting images]

What I've tried below seems to work on very small images but slows to a halt as the images get bigger. The bottleneck seems to occur where I assign common_points.

```
img1_array = process_image("Images/nhx.jpg", nheight)
img2_array = process_image("Images/ku.jpg", nheight)

img1_black = get_black_pixels(img1_array)
img2_black = get_black_pixels(img2_array)

# create all img1 3D points:
img1_3d = []
z1 = len(img2_array[1])  # number of img2 columns

for pixel in img1_black:
    for i in range(z1):
        img1_3d.append((pixel[0], pixel[1], i))  # (img1_row, img1_col, img2_col)

# create all img2 3D points:
img2_3d = []
z2 = len(img1_array[1])  # number of img1 columns

for pixel in img2_black:
    for i in range(z2):
        img2_3d.append((pixel[0], pixel[1], i))  # (img2_row, img2_col, img1_col)

# get all common 3D points
common_points = [x for x in img1_3d if x in img2_3d]

# get num_seeds number of random common_points
seed_indices = np.random.choice(len(common_points), num_seeds, replace=False)

seeds = []
for index_num in seed_indices:
    seeds.append(common_points[index_num])
```

Questions:

- How can I avoid the bottleneck? I haven't been able to come up with a numpy solution.
- Is there a better solution, in general, to how I am coding this?
- Any thoughts on how I could somewhat evenly disperse seeds?

**Update Edit:**

Based on Luke's algorithm, I've come up with the following working code. Is this the correct implementation? Could this be improved upon?

```
img1_array = process_image("Images/John.JPG", 500)
img2_array = process_image("Images/Ryan.jpg", 500)

img1_black = get_black_pixels(img1_array)
# img2_black = get_black_pixels(img2_array)

density = 0.00001
seeds = []

for img1_pixel in img1_black:
    row = img1_pixel[0]

    img2_row = np.array(np.nonzero(img2_array[row]))  # array of column numbers where there is a black pixel

    if np.any(img2_row):
        for img2_col in img2_row[0]:
            if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < density:
                seeds.append([row, img1_pixel[1], img2_col])
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is because you're comparing every 3D point in the "apple" shaded area to every 3D point in the "orange" shaded area, which is a huge number of comparisons. You could speed it up by a factor of imgHeight by only looking at points in the same row. You could also speed it up by storing img2_3d as a set instead of a list, because calling "in" on a set is much faster (it's an O(1) operation instead of an O(n) operation).

However, it's better to completely avoid making lists of all 3D points. Here's one solution:

1. Choose an arbitrary density parameter, call it Density. Try Density = 0.10 to fill in 10% of the intersection points.
2. For each black pixel in Apple, loop through the **black** pixels **in the same row** of Orange. If (random.uniform(0,1) < Density), create a 3D point at (applex, orangex, row) or whatever the correct arrangement is for your coordinate system.

That algorithm will sample evenly, so 3D areas with more black will have more samples. If I understand your last question, you want to sample more densely in areas with less black (though I'm not sure why). To do that you could:

1. Do a Gaussian blur of the inverse of your two images (OpenCV has functions for this), and multiply each times 0.9 and add 0.1. You now have an image that has a higher value where the image is more white.
2. Do the algorithm above, but for each pixel pair in step 2, set Density = blurredOrangePixel * blurredApplePixel. Thus, your selection density will be higher in white regions.

I would try the basic algorithm first though; I think it will look better.

Comment: Luke, thanks for the help! I didn't do a good job in explaining how and why I wanted a specific type of 'seed' distribution but your algorithm seems to distribute pixels nicely. If it becomes an issue , I'll cross that bridge at that time. One last question before I accept your answer, does my implementation look right?

Comment: The basic logic looks right to me. My guess is that it would work for tiny images. You could probably test it with something really tiny, like a couple 3x2 pixel images.